# Django pgtrigger class meta giving nameerror

Tags: django, postgresql

i am trying to implement postgress trigger in django for that i am using **django-pgtrigger**

i am learning to implement it from [this doc](https://django-pgtrigger.readthedocs.io/en/4.9.0/#quick-start)

but i am facing problem using the quickstart code

```
from django.db import models
import pgtrigger  # Make sure you import the necessary module

class ProtectedModel(models.Model):
    """Active object cannot be deleted!"""
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        triggers = [
            pgtrigger.Protect(
                name='protect_deletes',
                operation=pgtrigger.Delete,
                condition=pgtrigger.Q(old__is_active=True)
            )
        ]
```

problem:

> **NameError: name 'triggers' is not defined. Did you mean: 'pgtrigger'?**

i am looking an easy way to implement database log functionality using trigger. if there any better way than this than please suggest

Comment: did you add pgtriger to installed apps?

Comment: my bad , i mistaken the spelling of pgtrigger  in installed app ,  thanks issue solved now